# threads in c++ Linux waiting indefinitely

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

We have to write program which will create two threads. The first thread will ask for letter from keyboard and then it will send a signal to second thread which is waiting for it. Then it will change this letter to upper one and if this letter isn't 'E' it will send another signal to thread one.  What will make run threads again until letter you typed won't be 'e'.

Communication between both threads is somewhat similar to playing ping-pong, or at least it should be.

Below I'm adding piece of code I wrote. It's not finished but there's a problem I can't fix or find solution to. When I try to run this code it gets stuck. It looks like both threads are waiting for signal so nothing is happening.

What is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mut;
pthread_cond_t dadam;
pthread_cond_t dudum;

char x;

void *first(void *arg) {
  while(1) {  
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    pthread_cond_wait(&dadam, &mut);
    cout << "Type a letter\n";
    cin >> x; 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    pthread_cond_signal(&dudum);
  }
}

void *second(void *arg) { 
  while(1) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&dudum, &mut); 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    char y;
    y = toupper(x);
    cout << y << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    pthread_cond_signal(&dadam);
  }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t nun;
  pthread_t nuno;

  pthread_create(&nun, NULL, &first,NULL);
  pthread_create(&nuno, NULL, &second,NULL);
  pthread_cond_signal(&dadam);
  pthread_join(nun, NULL);
  pthread_join(nuno, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different approaches to this. Which are you intending to use? Apart from the (unnecesssary) `using namespace std` this is just C code. C++ has [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) to handle this.

Comment: Before you call `pthread_cond_wait`, you **must** check that the thing you want to wait for has not already happened. And before you continue on after `pthread_cond_wait` returns, you **must** check to make sure that the thing you want to wait for has already happened. Condition variables are stateless and have no idea what you're waiting for. It's 100% your responsibility to make sure you call `pthread_cond_wait` when, and only when, needed. The pattern is `pthread_mutex_lock(...); while (something_has_not_happened_yet) pthread_cond_wait(...); ...stuff.. pthread_mutex_unlock(...);`.

Comment: im using C. Tried before with c++ but after many tries some unwanted fragments still left, and to be honest i mixed what i wanted to do and type. Anyway sorry for problem and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the mutex variables.

Apart from that it seems the first thread will wait for the event `dadam`.
Be sure that event is generated for the thread `first`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize your mutex or your condition variables.  They have static duration and therefore participate in default initialization, but it is not guaranteed that that yields a usable state.  The general-purpose way to accomplish that is with `pthread_cond_init()` and `pthread_mutex_init()`, but if the defaults are sufficient then there are also initializer macros you can use:

```
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t dadam = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t dudum = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

You also attempt to wait on CV `dudum` without holding the specified mutex.  You need to be holding the mutex when you invoke `pthread_cond_wait()`:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
pthread_cond_wait(&dudum, &mut);
```

(not the other way around).

But the main problem appears to be a race condition in your implementation.

On each iteration of its loop, function `first()` waits on CV `dadam` before proceeding, and on each iteration of *its* loop, function `second()` waits on CV `dudum` before proceeding.  This might work if you could get it bootstrapped, but when you first start those two functions, neither one can proceed past its wait to signal the CV on which the other is waiting.  You signal `dadam` from the main thread, but if the main thread sends the signal before `first()` starts waiting then the signal will be lost.

Insufficient:

<s>Suggestion:</s>

1. Initialize the mutex and CVs properly.
2. Fix the problem with mutex scope in function `second()`; and
3. in `main()`, perform the thread creation (but not the joins) under protection of the mutex; and
4. in function `first()` (only) move the `pthread_cond_wait()` to the end of the loop (making sure to extend the scope of the mutex appropriately), so that `first()` doesn't have to wait for a signal to perform its first iteration; and
5. remove the `pthread_cond_signal()` from `main()`, as it is no longer necessary.

Note that it is safe to perform a `pthread_cond_signal()` while holding the target CV's associated mutex locked.  It is not required to do so, but some recommend it as good practice.

Comment: Refer to David Schwartz's comment on your question, as he's quite right.  My struck out suggestion is not sufficient to make your code do as he describes, and as a result, it is not sufficient.  To resolve the issue.

Comment: Most of the problems listed above was made when i tried to fix it by myself. The funniest part was i was trying to do it with the code my teacher gave us as help. Sadly it wasn't helpful at all. If can I ask out of my curiousity how should I do point 3? Well i fixed it and it works but i'm curious. Anyway Thank you a lot for help both of you.

Comment: @LukeS, you would do (3) by locking the mutex (`pthread_mutex_lock()`) before the first `pthread_create()`, and unlocking it after the second.

Comment: @Josh Bollinger Really, Thank you a lot. Thanks to your explanations i fixed it and understood where was problem with code and my thinking ;) Really thank you, and sorry for stupid questions. Thanks a lot once again and have nice day